# Z-score in-sample vs out-of-sample

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, means

I've always calculated the $Z_{score}$ of a value $x$ using the mean and standard deviation of a sample including $x$.
However I have been thinking whether it wouldn't be more correct to use the mean and standard deviation of the sample excluding $x$.

Example:

$x=5$

$S = {1,2,3,4}$

$Z_{score}=({x-\mu})/\sigma = 1.26 $ where $\mu = \sum_{i=1}^5 i/5 = 3$ and $\sigma = 1.58$

$Z^{'}_{score}=({x-\mu^{'}})/\sigma^{'} = 1.94$ where $\mu^{'}=\sum_{i=1}^4 i/4=2.5$ and $\sigma^{'} = 1.29$

In most practical cases this doesn't seem to be significantly different, but I'm no statistician.

What are the pros and cons of using each method?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: Could you please write down formally what you mean by including/excluding $x$ in your calculations?

Comment: Added an example, hope that clarifies. Understand that the latter approach might not be considered a $Z_{score}$.